# Module dependencies when using template function specializations

Tags: c++, dependencies, template-specialization, c++20

Please check out the following code snippet (pseudo code, didn't compile it):

A.h

```
template <typename T>
void SubTest(T t) = delete;

template <>
void SubTest(int i)
{
    cout << i;
}

template <typename T>
class MyClass
{
    public:
        void Test(T t)
        {
            SubTest(t);
        }
}
```

B.h

```
class X{};

template <>
void SubTest(X x)
{
    cout << x;
}
```

As you can see I want a class template method to call a function template. That function is specialized in various ways. Some of the specializations are located in A.h, some in other in optional headers (like B.h).
I want to avoid A.h to be dependent from B.h etc. since A.h can work standalone but should be extendable by an number of other other modules providing specializations. Logically this dependency is not necessary but it seems technically it can not be avoided.

AFAIK C++ requires two conditions:

1. All specilizations need to be declared before they are used
2. The primary function prototype must be declared before each specialization

I could include A.h in B.h. or I could repeat `template <typename T> void SubTest(T t) = delete;` in B.h to fulfill condition 2. However this still wouldn't fulfill 1.

I could include B.h in the middle of A.h but that would create a (logically) unwanted dependency.

Is there a way to solve this problem at compile time in C++ up to C++20?

Comment: why do you think `A.h` depends on `B.h` ?

Comment: If A.h. includes B.h. I can not use A.h without B.h. Or what else do you mean?

Comment: why would `A.h` include `B.h` ? What you write I understand as if `A.h` depends on `B.h`. Someone who want to use the specialization `Subtest<X>` already inclduded `A.h` for `Subtest` and `B.h` for `X`, so I dont see the problem

Comment: `B.h` has to include `A.h`, otherwise clients who include them in the wrong order (`B.h`, then `A.h`) get a compilation error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it’s true that specializations “need to be declared before they are used”, that doesn’t mean before their caller is **defined**, but before it is **instantiated** so as to *use* the specialization in question.  This is critical to any customization scheme: you define the base case, then clients `#include` that and define specializations for their classes immediately after their definitions.  Further clients necessarily have the specializations available if they have the classes available, so everything works.  None of this has changed since **C++98**.

(Meanwhile, you can’t repeat `=delete` for a function: that counts as a definition, and must appear on the first declaration as well.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wrote a follow-up question, maybe you are interested: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61768725/1421332