# Dependencies when using C++20 conceptual template function specialization

Tags: c++, dependencies, template-specialization, c++20, c++-concepts

I was doing some tests with the following C++20 code (built with current GCC10):

```
template <typename ToT, typename FromT>
ToT myfunction(const FromT& pFrom) = delete;

template <typename ToT, typename FromT>
struct myclass
{
   inline ToT myclassmethod(const FromT& pFrom)
   {
      return myfunction<ToT, FromT>(pFrom);
   }
};

/* C++20 concepts code */
template <std::same_as<std::string> ToT, std::integral FromT>
inline ToT myfunction(const FromT& pFrom)
{
   return std::to_string(pFrom);
}

template <std::same_as<std::string> ToT, std::floating_point FromT>
inline ToT myfunction(const FromT& pFrom)
{
   return std::to_string(pFrom);
}

/* Alternative conventional code
template <>
inline std::string myfunction(const int& pFrom)
{
   return std::to_string(pFrom);
}

template <>
inline std::string myfunction(const double& pFrom)
{
   return std::to_string(pFrom);
}
*/

int main(int pArgc, char* pArgv[]) noexcept
{
   std::cout << myclass<std::string, int>().myclassmethod(10);
   std::cout << myclass<std::string, double>().myclassmethod(0.666);

   return 0;
}
```

When using the conventional code, everything compiles fine. The specializations are used as they should. When using the C++20 code instead, I get errors "use of deleted function".

I would have expected the C++20 concepts specializations to work in the same way the conventional specializations do, but obviously there is a differences that makes it impossible to define such specializations independently (see related question [Module dependencies when using template function specializations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61760083/1421332)).

Is this the desired behavior in C++20? Is there a way in C++20 to customize a conceptual function template independently (i.e. define the specialization without declaration or definition before calling it)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those aren’t specializations, but **overloads**.  As such, if they appear after their caller they are found *only* by ADL.  As usual, you can use partial specializations (constrained ones in this case) with a [forwarding wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4914414/8586227).  (Of course, that’s not very interesting with `std::same_as`.)

Comment: Ok, I see. In a famous german C++ article series, such kind of overloads are explicitly called specializations so obviously I expected the wrong behavior.

Comment: Could you share a link that explains how to use forwarding wrappers to use partial specialization. I didn't use it before and I could not find information using that term.

Comment: Do you know if there are any compilers providing extensions for partial specialization support?

Comment: @Silicomancer: Partial specializations (of *class* templates) are a C++98 feature!  (They also work for variable templates since those were introduced in C++14, but that’s not relevant here.)

Comment: Sure. Both of my comments were about partial template function specializations.

Comment: @Silicomancer: Neither “template function”s nor *function template* partial specializations exist, so I don’t know how to interpret your comments in that case.

Comment: Sorry. I'm not a native speaker. Is this a language problem? Let me rephrase: 1. Could you please explain the "forwarding wrapper" mentioned in your answer? 2. Do you know if there are compilers with non-standard extensions enabling function template partial specializations?

Comment: @Silicomancer: Sorry for the confusion; I added a link.  I don’t know of any such extension, but I can’t say I’ve looked since I would always just use the standard, wrapper approach.